# Specifying additional source folders in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, workspace

I'm porting two AS3 projects to TS using Visual Studio Code.

The second project uses code from the first project's folders.
I wonder if it is possible to specify additional source folders outside the main source folder in Visual Studio Code, like in the old good FlashBuilder.

For example:

```
Main source folder: "src"
Additional folders: ["../previous_project/src", "../previous_project/libs"]
```

This way I can use or extend classes from the external projects like if they were saved in the main source folder.

Investigating a bit I've found that the 'Insiders' version of Visual Studio Code have something called 'multi-root workspaces'. I made some experiment with it, but I must be doing something wrong: When compiling, I get:

```
"error TS6059: File is not under 'rootDir'.
'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files."
```

So, how do I specify additional source folders in Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing a bit more with workspaces, it seems that commeting out "rootDir" in tsconfig.json removes 'error TS6059'. Now I can compile with no issues.

It would be good to see a correct example of multi-root workspaces, though.

Comment: Although I've solved the issue, I'm not clear if this is the best way to work with multiple source paths. At this moment 'workspaces' are not part of the stable version of VSC, so hopefully there will be more information about this in the future.